# How to run a Electron Windows APP on wine

Tags: electron

I have a very specific problem:

**I need to open my compiled windows electron app on linux on wine (https://www.winehq.org/).**

How to do this?

---

- I know electron give a easy way to compile a Linux version of my APP, but in my case it is not possible...
- My Electron APP as made for Windows, it change Windows registery and other stuff to auxiliary other APP
- My Electron APP have to run in same workspace as another APP that i didn't made

---

This is the errors i got when i try to run the windows electron app on playonlinux:

https://i.ibb.co/zP6K5R4/Screenshot-from-2021-03-31-17-14-14.png

https://i.ibb.co/N6SFwr5/Screenshot-from-2021-03-31-17-14-18.png

```
full errors: 
https://pastebin.com/iM2YAUaW
```

https://i.ibb.co/VpypMHd/Screenshot-from-2021-03-31-17-14-31.png

---

I made this electron app as a auxiliary application for other windows app that is not mine, so i have to run they both together on Wine...

Normally this other APP run on Wine (it works), but the auxiliary electron APP that i made don't

I don't like to use windows, i need to run this on Wine.
How to do it?

Comment: From your logs I see that your wine version is pretty old: Wine build: wine-2.0.3. Try to use wine 6.0

Comment: i've create a new pool on playonlinux 64bits with wine 6.0
when i run the electron installer, everything looks work
just in the end, when program runs a new better problem shows:
just like this: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/mesa/mesa/uploads/19a8676adb7c18e4f6e4c66b43e6cc24/image.png
the audio is working, the hover effect change cursor, but i can't see anything
what should i do?